# Firebase reset password with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have React project where I have to implement reset password option. Managed to do that and password reset is working as it should. But have problem with next step where I have to create button that lead user to his email provider.

I thought about slicing entered email address and take just email domain, passing that to button function to open full link, but that won't work for custom made domains of some company. Since the return value of sendPasswordResetEmail is void I can't get any info about email provider. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Hello. Not sure I fully understand your question. You want to know what to do with a domain that is custom (i.e. not gmail, yahoo, etc)? What are the product guidelines for that scenario?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Hey mate.In project they specified it like this. If user reset password lead him to next component where you should have button to open link of email provider(Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook). So if users email is example@gmail.com I know that button should navigate to 'mail.google.com', but how can I do it when user have email like example@somerandomdomain.com, then I can't just open gmail or yahoo. In my company we have compay name as domain, and we use Outlook. Yeah you understood question, don't know what should I do with custom domains